# PHP cookies and member security

Tags: php, html, security, cookies

I've created a forum which uses a PHP session when logged in to determine the user id, and cookies for log-term login.

I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is this the best/securest method?
2. Cookies can be added manually via the address bar with javascript, which is a huge security risk. Is there any way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to store in the cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you are using https and not http.  This will keep your traffic from getting sniffed and exploited.

Secondly, generate as random a value as possible to use as a token in the cookie.  This is how many of the big sites do their user tracking.  Have a map of token to user on the server side that tracks the identities.  Remember:  Anything that comes from the client is untrusted and could be tampered with.

Third, use an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) to make tampering much more difficult.  You don't want users being able to brute force other tokens.

EDIT:

You may find these other SO questions/answers helpful as you build this system:

1. Long details about creating and using tokens (doesn't necessarily have to be a REST service to be applicable):  [REST Web Service authentication token implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490265/rest-web-service-authentication-token-implementation/15490642#15490642)
2. Creating good tokens (don't use microtime): [Is using microtime() to generate password-reset tokens bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527706/is-using-microtime-to-generate-password-reset-tokens-bad-practice/15530476#15530476)

Comment: Also send a IP with the login session so you can check server side if the session is not stolen.

Comment: You're welcome!  I just added a couple of links to other questions that will be useful to you.

Comment: @S.Visser so if I move my laptop from home to the office I have to log in again?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben : Thanks you! This really opens my eyes to how negligent I've been with website security.